# Button in WPF acting in strange way with isMouseOver

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am having a funny issue here with WPF and a button styled. Problem is it contains a path and isMouseOver seems to only trigger when the mouse pointer is over the path but not over the button. That is I have to move the mouse pointer over the white figure inside the button to have the button shaded. Is as if the button wouldn't exist and only the path would.

This is the code for the button:

```
<Button Grid.Column="5" x:Name="btnClose" Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="White"
        BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}"
        Command="{Binding ExitCommand}">
    <Path Data="M0,0 L16,16 M16,0 L0,16" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" 
          Margin="0,1,0,0" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" />
</Button>
```

And this is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13.5"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="2.5" 
                        x:Name="ButtonBorder" 
                        BorderThickness="1.2" 
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">

                        <Border x:Name="ButtonShine" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <!--<Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="1" RenderingBias="Quality" Direction="270" />
                                </Border.Effect>-->
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Border x:Name="shadowMouseOver" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Hidden"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                Background="#7F171717">
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="shadowDisabled" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Hidden"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                Background="#AFFFFFFF">
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="#FFDEDEDE" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="shadowDisabled" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="shadowMouseOver" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Button.RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Button.RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.95" ScaleY="0.95"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="shadowMouseOver" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ButtonShine" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                     <GradientStop Color="#FFBFBFBF" Offset="1"/>
                                     <GradientStop Color="#FF383838"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="ButtonShine" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBFBFBF" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF383838"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                         </Setter>
                     </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Any ideas? Bug in WPF? Something not done properly?

Comment: Could not try but have you checked to set `IsHitTestVisible` to `true` for the button? Also what helped me in this issue in the past often was to set a background, even if it was `Transparent`.

Comment: Thanks. I added the property and nothing. Is strange cause once I hit the path and I move the mouse out of it but still the pointer is over the button it stays shaded and is returned to normal only after I move the pointer outside the button. How you set that background? I am gonna investigate.

Comment: I added this and nothing. <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0000" Offset="0"/>
                                    
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFAFD1F8" Offset="0.53"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

Comment: Is like if the button would appear. Even double clicking on what would be the area of the button makes the window maximize as if clicking on the taskbar. After I hover the pointer makes the button appear and stay like that until I move it out.

Comment: Ok seems I missunderstood the background part and I correctly saw what you meant when the other person answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not a bug, but due to the fact that you provide no background for the control in its template for the default state; thus, the hit test fails in the region outside of the path.  If you notice, both `shadowMouseOver` and `shadowDisabled`, the only two borders that provide any background, are not visible unless the appropriate events are triggered.  Thus, they are not visible to hit tests.  Your path, on the other hand, is visible and so it's able to trigger events.

See [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752097(v=vs.100).aspx) at MSDN for more information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752097(v=vs.100).aspx

Just in case that link fails some time in the future, here's one of the parts that pretty much summarizes what I'm trying to say here:

> The purpose of the HitTest methods in the VisualTreeHelper class is to
>   determine whether a geometry or point coordinate value is within the
>   rendered content of a given object, such as a control or graphic
>   element. For example, you could use hit testing to determine whether a
>   mouse click within the bounding rectangle of an object falls within
>   the geometry of a circle. You can also choose to override the default
>   implementation of hit testing to perform your own custom hit test
>   calculations. The following illustration shows the relationship
>   between a non-rectangular object's region and its bounding rectangle.

[image]

You have a couple of options if you wish to maintain the transparent background look.  Either set that background to `Transparent`, due to the fact that transparent objects are visible to hits tests, or set it to some color, while turning its opacity down to 0.  Best place for that background would probably be at `ButtonBorder` (most outer border), but it'll be your decision to make.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your helpful answer. I really could understand now since you explained it better.

Comment: @WaldoAlvarez No problem.